# asp.net access dynamic controls within a dynamic control

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a requirement to build an advanced search feature based on items that are selected in a drop down view.

I have build a table programmatically  in asp.net, and in this table I have also dynamically added a label, textbox and drop down control.

These all render fine, however the part that I am stuck is getting the values back from the textbox and subsequent drop down list.

This is how the tables is being built

```
Public Sub buildAdvancedOptions()

        'Creat the Table and Add it to the Page
        Dim table As New Table()
        table.ID = "advancedTable"
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(table)


        For i As Integer = 0 To _dictOfClassAndCol.Count() - 1
            Dim row As New TableRow()

            Dim labelCell As New TableCell()
            Dim textCell As New TableCell()
            Dim optionsCell As New TableCell()
            Dim tb As New TextBox()
            Dim lbl As New Label()
            Dim ddl As New DropDownList()

            ' Set a unique ID for each TextBox added
            lbl.Text = _dictOfClassAndCol.Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString()
            lbl.ID = "lbl" & _dictOfClassAndCol.Keys.ElementAt(i)
            tb.ID = "txt" & _dictOfClassAndCol.Keys.ElementAt(i)
            ddl.ID = "ddl" & _dictOfClassAndCol.Keys.ElementAt(i)
            ddl.Items.Add("is equal to")
            ddl.Items.Add("is not equal to")
            ddl.Items.Add("is like")
            ddl.Items.Add("is not like")
            ddl.Items.Add("contains")
            ddl.Items.Add("between")

            labelCell.Controls.Add(lbl)
            textCell.Controls.Add(tb)
            optionsCell.Controls.Add(ddl)
            ' Add the TableCell to the TableRow
            row.Cells.Add(labelCell)
            row.Cells.Add(textCell)
            row.Cells.Add(optionsCell)
            row.Attributes.Add("class", _dictOfClassAndCol.Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString().Replace(" ", ""))

            ' Add the TableRow to the Table
            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        advanced.Controls.Add(table)


    End Sub
```

This is how i am trying to get the values of the textbox and drop down list so that I can pass them onto another function to build a string.

```
Protected Sub btnAdvancedSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdvancedSearch.Click

        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        Dim message As String = ""
        For Each control As table In advanced.Controls.OfType(Of table)()                
            message += control.ID + ": " + control.ID  + "\n"
        Next
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" & message & "');", True)

    End Sub
```

I can see that I am building the right amount of rows and cells, but cannot get into the table control called `"advancedTable"` in order to find the controls in here.

Any and all help on how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of `buildAdvancedOptions()` the table is being added to `Page.Form.Controls`, then at the end you have `advanced.Controls.Add(table)`. Based on the code in the button click event, I see no need for adding it to `Page.Form.Controls`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) function and casting the Table:

```
Dim tblTarget As Table = CType(advanced.FindControl("advancedTable"), Table)

Dim strMessage As String = String.Empty

For Each objControl As Control In tblTarget.Controls

    strMessage += objControl.ID & " / "

Next
```

Additional code will be required for iterating through the rows/cells, determining the Type of the search parameter Controls (DropDown vs TextBox) and getting their values, but this should at least get you a handle on the Table.

Comment: sorry for the late reply a Windows 10 BSOD occured and i lost a day of work, will get back to you to see if this works later on

Comment: You do add it to the Form, so perhaps try Page.Form.FindControl("advancedTable) instead of advanced.FindControl.